# ReactJS onChange function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-native, onchange

Where am I going wrong with my onChange function? I want to be able to type in my textbox, but I keep getting the following console error when I recompile:

```
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined**
```

See code below:

```
var name = "";
export default React.createClass({

  handleChange: function() {
    this.props.onUserInput(
        this.refs.name.value    
    )
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
        <Well style={style.well}>
          <div style={style.userContent}>

            <input style={style.userDetails} 
                   id ="userName" 
                   type="text" 
                   onChange={this.handleChange()} 
                   value ={name} />

              <Button bsStyle="primary">Update</Button>
          </div>
        </Well>         
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Do `this.handleChange` instead of `this.handleChange()`

Answer (score 3):

Remove `()`., to `onChange` you have to pass *reference* to function

```
onChange={ this.handleChange }
```

**Update:**

Also, in this case, you don't need `refs`, because you can get value like so

```
handleChange: function (event) {
  this.props.onUserInput(
    event.currentTarget.value    
  )
},
```

Based on your example, I see that you use variable `name`, it is bad practice, I think in this case you can use `state`, like in my example

```js
const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      value: ''
    }
  },
  
  handleChange: function (event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.currentTarget.value
    }, () => { // arrow function, ES2015
      console.log(this.state.value);
      // call this.props.onUserInput(this.state.value)
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <input style={ {} } 
        id="userName" 
        type="text" 
        onChange={ this.handleChange } 
        value={ this.state.value } 
      />
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, two things are going on.

First, `this.refs.name` is `undefined`, and you can't read the property `value` of `undefined` (as the error says). You never created the `ref` in your `render()` method. Read the [React docs on the ref attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to better understand how it works, and the inherent limitations.

Second, you're *invoking* the `handleChange` function instead of just *passing* it as `onChange`:

```
onChange={this.handleChange()} // you CALL the function with ()
```

Instead, pass it directly:

```
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

Note that if you switch to ES6 `class` components, you'll also need to bind the function (otherwise `this` will be `undefined` when `handleChange` runs):

```
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```

For now, `React.createClass` is doing the binding for you.

Comment: I've edited my code above, I have declared "name" in my code, I forgot to add it to my snippet above.

Comment: You're still missing the `ref`. Did you read the link I posted?